# zfs send of 7TB snapshot to S3 upload results in "An error occurred (Unknown) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zfs

I have a CentOS 7.4.1708 server that I am attempting to backup via AWS S3.  Kernel is 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.  Since the filesystem I'm trying to backup is ZFS and I have it on scheduled snapshots, I believed I could do a ZFS send to S3 and backup my files that way.

This is command I attempted:

```
zfs send <snapshot> | aws s3 cp --expected-size=$((1024*1024*1024 * 7000)) - s3://s3bucket/snapshot image name
```

The `--expected-size` corresponds to 7.5 TB.  My snapshot image is around 7.35TB.  I had thought this command would allow me to send my image to S3 but this has unfortunately resulted in an error message after running fine for a few days:

```
upload failed: - to s3://home-data/nfs-home@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2018-06-14-1004.img
An error occurred (Unknown) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation (reached max retries: 4): Unknown
```

Does anyone know what I have to do differently to avoid this error?

Comment: "An error occurred (Unknown)" isn't a helpful message. But you mention you have 7.5TB that you're trying to fit into 7.35TB; that doesn't sound like a winning strategy to me. Even assuming it's the other way around, you need to account for any amount reserved for the administrator.

Comment: S3 has a maximum object size of 5 TB.